# Is the word "gig" formal?

Tags: formality, colloquialisms

I'd like to know whether the word **gig** (temporary job) is formal or colloquial.

Always that I've read it, it has been in forums. I have never heard it or read it somewhere else, just in forums, which make me wonder about the formality of this word.

Comment: What does [AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/gig) , for instance, say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Colloquial when referring to any job, usually just used for casual employment, e.g. "I got a gig as a gardener for a few weeks".

But if you're a musician, I'd think you could use it formally and it would make sense.

Answer (score 4):

GIG noun:
:  a job usually for a specified time; especially :  an entertainer's engagement.

Source: Merriam-Webster Dictionary

gig (n.2) 
"job," first used by jazz musicians, attested from 1915 but said to have been in use c.1905; of uncertain origin. As a verb, by 1939. Related: Gigged; gigging.
Source: Etymology online

Given the origin and use I'd say it is used more on a colloquial basis.